# Jest: How can I use dynamic environment variable?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, environment-variables

**Context**

For some reason, I'm using environment variables(development, production...) dynamically by inserting script tag into `index.html`. In that script, I defined global variable that contains environment variables.

**env.js**

```js
window.globalConfig = {
  REACT_APP_SERVER_URL: "http://api.somesite.co.kr"
}
```

`App.tsx` uses this variable at runtime, but `App.test.tsx` is failed causing error like below.

> ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'REACT_APP_SERVER_URL' of undefined***

**index.html**

```html
<script src="./env.js"></script>
<script src="./bundle.js></script>
```

**App.test.tsx**

```js
it('render App', () => {
  render(<App />);
});
```

**App.tsx**

```js
...window.globalConfig('REACT_APP_SERVER_URL')...
```

How can I use dynamic variable in Jest when I use script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CRA(Create-React-App), `react-scripts` uses `setupTests.ts` file, so if you import file which contains global variables, it is solved.

**setupTests.ts**

```js
import './env.js'
```